# Change the format of JavaScript array when source is PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently working on laravel and my project requires me to use autocomplete for dropdowns.

However, the object returned from the following

```
$companies = Companies::all()->pluck('company_name','id')->toArray();
```

and converted to js array using the following

```
var companies = <?php echo json_encode($companies) ?>;
```

returns the following format of array

```
{ 2: "Jadon Technology", 
    58: "Samsung",
    59: "Sony",
    60: "Sujan",
    61: "Superman", 
    68: "Vivo", 
    84: "Iphone", 
    85: "Oppo", 
  }
```

I want the array as given below.

```
var companies = [
    { id: 2, value: "Jadon Technology"} , 
    { id: 58, value: "Samsung"} ,
    { id: 59, value: "Sony"} ,
    { id: 60, value: "Sujan"} ,
    { id: 61, value: "Superman"} , 
    { id: 68, value: "Vivo"} , 
    { id: 84, value: "Iphone"} , 
    { id: 85, value: "Oppo"} , 
  ];
```

Am i doing something wrong or is there any other way to convert into said format? Please someone help me. Suggestions including php/laravel/javascript oriented are welcomed. 
PS: no foreach loop because i have to implement the same in numerous places in the same project.

Comment: _“no foreach loop because i have to implement the same in numerous places in the same project.”_ - that in itself is not an argument against using a simple loop to do this, but for making this into a function.

Comment: i may be wrong here because i'm not super familiar with laravel, but your problem seems to be [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck). the collection itself would be in key/value if you need to narrow your results possibly map() is the right function.

Comment: Look up the differences between objects and arrays in Javascript, it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not implement a function to do the work, then call the function before json_encode:

```
   function convert($arr) { 
       $tmp = array();
       foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
          $tmp[] = array("id" => $k, "value" => $v)
       }
       return $tmp;
    }
```

Comment: This is much better and fits perfectly with the code i have. Thank you too

Answer (score 2):

The [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck) function formats the data that way, the first parameter is the value key and the second is the key value. If you want key value pairs, you should use [`select`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#selects).

```
$companies = Companies::select('company_name', 'id')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This finishes my whole days work in seconds.